# How to run a trained PyTorch Model on my sample inputs?

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, image-segmentation

So I am trying to perform RGBD segmentation and am using this git repo:-
https://github.com/zanilzanzan/FuseNet_PyTorch

However, there is no way to run inference on our own samples, so I tried to define the model myself and import the weights from the repo, here is the code for the same

```
class FuseNet(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, num_labels, gpu_device=0, use_class=True):
    super(FuseNet, self).__init__()

    # Load pre-trained VGG-16 weights to two separate variables.
    # They will be used in defining the depth and RGB encoder sequential layers.
    feats = list(models.vgg16(pretrained=True).features.children())
    feats2 = list(models.vgg16(pretrained=True).features.children())

    # Average the first layer of feats variable, the input-layer weights of VGG-16,
    # over the channel dimension, as depth encoder will be accepting one-dimensional
    # inputs instead of three.
    avg = torch.mean(feats[0].cuda(gpu_device).weight.data, dim=1)
    avg = avg.unsqueeze(1)

    bn_moment = 0.1
    self.use_class = use_class

    if use_class:
        num_classes = 10

    # DEPTH ENCODER
    self.conv11d = nn.Conv2d(1, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1).cuda(gpu_device)
    self.conv11d.weight.data = avg

    self.CBR1_D = nn.Sequential(
        nn.BatchNorm2d(64).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats[1].cuda(gpu_device),
        feats[2].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(64).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats[3].cuda(gpu_device),
    )
    self.CBR2_D = nn.Sequential(
        feats[5].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(128).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats[6].cuda(gpu_device),
        feats[7].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(128).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats[8].cuda(gpu_device),
    )
    self.CBR3_D = nn.Sequential(
        feats[10].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(256).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats[11].cuda(gpu_device),
        feats[12].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(256).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats[13].cuda(gpu_device),
        feats[14].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(256).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats[15].cuda(gpu_device),
    )
    self.dropout3_d = nn.Dropout(p=0.5).cuda(gpu_device)

    self.CBR4_D = nn.Sequential(
        feats[17].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats[18].cuda(gpu_device),
        feats[19].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats[20].cuda(gpu_device),
        feats[21].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats[22].cuda(gpu_device),
    )
    self.dropout4_d = nn.Dropout(p=0.5).cuda(gpu_device)

    self.CBR5_D = nn.Sequential(
        feats[24].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats[25].cuda(gpu_device),
        feats[26].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats[27].cuda(gpu_device),
        feats[28].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats[29].cuda(gpu_device),
    )

    # RGB ENCODER
    self.CBR1_RGB = nn.Sequential(
        feats2[0].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(64).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats2[1].cuda(gpu_device),
        feats2[2].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(64).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats2[3].cuda(gpu_device),
    )

    self.CBR2_RGB = nn.Sequential(
        feats2[5].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(128).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats2[6].cuda(gpu_device),
        feats2[7].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(128).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats2[8].cuda(gpu_device),
    )

    self.CBR3_RGB = nn.Sequential(
        feats2[10].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(256).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats2[11].cuda(gpu_device),
        feats2[12].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(256).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats2[13].cuda(gpu_device),
        feats2[14].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(256).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats2[15].cuda(gpu_device),
    )
    self.dropout3 = nn.Dropout(p=0.5).cuda(gpu_device)

    self.CBR4_RGB = nn.Sequential(
        feats2[17].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats2[18].cuda(gpu_device),
        feats2[19].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats2[20].cuda(gpu_device),
        feats2[21].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats2[22].cuda(gpu_device),
    )
    self.dropout4 = nn.Dropout(p=0.5).cuda(gpu_device)

    self.CBR5_RGB = nn.Sequential(
        feats2[24].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats2[25].cuda(gpu_device),
        feats2[26].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats2[27].cuda(gpu_device),
        feats2[28].cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512).cuda(gpu_device),
        feats2[29].cuda(gpu_device),
    )
    self.dropout5 = nn.Dropout(p=0.5).cuda(gpu_device)

    if use_class:
        self.ClassHead = nn.Sequential(
            # classifier[0].cuda(gpu_device),
            nn.Linear(35840, 4096).cuda(gpu_device),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.5).cuda(gpu_device),
            nn.Linear(4096, 4096).cuda(gpu_device),
            # classifier[3].cuda(gpu_device),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.5).cuda(gpu_device),
            nn.Linear(4096, num_classes).cuda(gpu_device)
        )

    # RGB DECODER
    self.CBR5_Dec = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512, momentum=bn_moment).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.ReLU().cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512, momentum=bn_moment).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.ReLU().cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512, momentum=bn_moment).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.ReLU().cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.Dropout(p=0.5).cuda(gpu_device),
    )

    self.CBR4_Dec = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512, momentum=bn_moment).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.ReLU().cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=3, padding=1).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512, momentum=bn_moment).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.ReLU().cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.Conv2d(512, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(256, momentum=bn_moment).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.ReLU().cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.Dropout(p=0.5).cuda(gpu_device),
    )

    self.CBR3_Dec = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(256, momentum=bn_moment).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.ReLU().cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(256, momentum=bn_moment).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.ReLU().cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.Conv2d(256,  128, kernel_size=3, padding=1).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(128, momentum=bn_moment).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.ReLU().cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.Dropout(p=0.5).cuda(gpu_device),
    )

    self.CBR2_Dec = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(128, momentum=bn_moment).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.ReLU().cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.Conv2d(128, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(64, momentum=bn_moment).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.ReLU().cuda(gpu_device),
    )

    self.CBR1_Dec = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(64, momentum=bn_moment).cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.ReLU().cuda(gpu_device),
        nn.Conv2d(64, num_labels, kernel_size=3, padding=1).cuda(gpu_device),
    )

    print('[INFO] FuseNet model has been created')
    self.initialize_weights()

# He Initialization for the linear layers in the classification head
def initialize_weights(self):
    for m in self.modules():
        if isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
            size = m.weight.size()
            fan_out = size[0]  # number of rows
            fan_in = size[1]  # number of columns
            variance = np.sqrt(4.0/(fan_in + fan_out))
            m.weight.data.normal_(0.0, variance)

def forward(self, rgb_inputs, depth_inputs):
    # DEPTH ENCODER
    # Stage 1
    x = self.conv11d(depth_inputs)
    x_1 = self.CBR1_D(x)
    x, id1_d = F.max_pool2d(x_1, kernel_size=2, stride=2, return_indices=True)

    # Stage 2
    x_2 = self.CBR2_D(x)
    x, id2_d = F.max_pool2d(x_2, kernel_size=2, stride=2, return_indices=True)

    # Stage 3
    x_3 = self.CBR3_D(x)
    x, id3_d = F.max_pool2d(x_3, kernel_size=2, stride=2, return_indices=True)
    x = self.dropout3_d(x)

    # Stage 4
    x_4 = self.CBR4_D(x)
    x, id4_d = F.max_pool2d(x_4, kernel_size=2, stride=2, return_indices=True)
    x = self.dropout4_d(x)

    # Stage 5
    x_5 = self.CBR5_D(x)

    # RGB ENCODER
    # Stage 1
    y = self.CBR1_RGB(rgb_inputs)
    y = torch.add(y, x_1)
    y, id1 = F.max_pool2d(y, kernel_size=2, stride=2, return_indices=True)

    # Stage 2
    y = self.CBR2_RGB(y)
    y = torch.add(y, x_2)
    y, id2 = F.max_pool2d(y, kernel_size=2, stride=2, return_indices=True)

    # Stage 3
    y = self.CBR3_RGB(y)
    y = torch.add(y, x_3)
    y, id3 = F.max_pool2d(y, kernel_size=2, stride=2, return_indices=True)
    y = self.dropout3(y)

    # Stage 4
    y = self.CBR4_RGB(y)
    y = torch.add(y,x_4)
    y, id4 = F.max_pool2d(y, kernel_size=2, stride=2, return_indices=True)
    y = self.dropout4(y)

    # Stage 5
    y = self.CBR5_RGB(y)
    y = torch.add(y, x_5)
    y_size = y.size()

    y, id5 = F.max_pool2d(y, kernel_size=2, stride=2, return_indices=True)
    y = self.dropout5(y)

    if self.use_class:
        # FC Block for Scene Classification
        y_class = y.view(y.size(0), -1)
        y_class = self.ClassHead(y_class)

    # DECODER
    # Stage 5 dec
    y = F.max_unpool2d(y, id5, kernel_size=2, stride=2, output_size=y_size)
    y = self.CBR5_Dec(y)

    # Stage 4 dec
    y = F.max_unpool2d(y, id4, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
    y = self.CBR4_Dec(y)

    # Stage 3 dec
    y = F.max_unpool2d(y, id3, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
    y = self.CBR3_Dec(y)

    # Stage 2 dec
    y = F.max_unpool2d(y, id2, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
    y = self.CBR2_Dec(y)

    # Stage 1 dec
    y = F.max_unpool2d(y, id1, kernel_size=2, stride=2)
    y = self.CBR1_Dec(y)

    if self.use_class:
        return y, y_class
    return y

model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path),strict=False)
```

But after this when I try to make predictions I get an error due to the input not being the correct dimensions. I am trying to put in an image in the format (1,320,240) as one of the parameters but it says it expects a 4-D array. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to infer on your own image:

```py
rgb_image = cv2.imread("PATH_TO_RGB_IMAGE",0)
depth_image = cv2.imread("PATH_TO_DEPTH_IMAGE",0)
rgb_image = rgb_image/255.0 #normalization
depth_image = depth_image/255.0 #normalization

model = FuseNet()
model.eval()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load("PATH_TO_MODEL"),strict=False)
output_seg, output_class = model(rgb_inputs.unsqueeze(0), d_inputs.unsqueeze(0))
```

The problem with shape is that the model expects input of shape [BatchSize, Channel, Height, Width] and the current input was [Channel, Height, Width], using Unsqueeze adds an extra dimension to the input and should work.

Comment: add ```with torch.no_grad:``` before last line?

Comment: Added `model.eval()` which should do the same.